# Find and replace in notepad for large file++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have an XML file that has 9000 lines in it.

Each XML node has about 10 attributes in it.

One of the attributes is:

```
<CreatedDate>2009-10-26T02:39:24</CreatedDate>
```

What I need to do is change the format of the DateTime to:

```
<CreatedDate>27/05/2010 07:30:16</CreatedDate>
```

But I do not know how to do it.

I know I could write a Regex to identify each value that needs to be replaced, but how can  make it only change the values I want and maintain the rest?

I have thought about writing a macro, but the document is too big to format in a way that I could predict where the element I want ot change is, and searching for something does not seem to work on a macro.

Any ideas? - I am sure it can be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change datetimes format only inside `<CreatedDate>` tags, try the regex replace in Notepad++ like this:

Replace this:

```
<CreatedDate>(\d{4})\-(\d{2})\-(\d{2})T([\d\:]*)</CreatedDate>
```

With this:

```
<CreatedDate>$3/$2/$1 $4</CreatedDate>
```

We refer to each parentheses using a $ symbol and it's position, so we can use those values in the replacing result.

Answer (score 2):

Find:

```
 <CreatedDate>(\d\d\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d)T(\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d)</CreatedDate>
```

Replace:

```
  <CreatedDate>\3/\2/\1 \4:\5:\6</CreatedDate>
```

\d matches a Digit.
And the braces create a group that you reference with e.g. \1

Answer (score 1):

Find this

```
<CreatedDate>(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})<\/CreatedDate>
```

Replace with:

```
<CreatedDate>\3/\2/\1 \4<\/CreatedDate>
```